# Windows 8 does not recognize VMware Usb Device

Tags: windows-8, vmware-workstation

I installed windows 8  a few hours ago. Then I installed vmware 9 workstation. Windows 8 gives a warning  'usb device not recognized  or is defective'. There is yellow exclamation on vmware usb device in device manage. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: No drivers for the device?  Does VM workstation support Win 8?

Comment: The device is virtual device of vmware. There is no its driver. Vm workstation supports win8.

Comment: Have you contacted vmware?  They could most likely easily answer your question.

Comment: I havent contected vmware. It has never been such a problem in the previous installation. I installed windows again. And the problem is occured.

Comment: tried to delete the troubled device from the list and re-detect it?

Answer (score 0):

That device may not have a driver for Windows 8 yet. You are best of contacting them asking if there is a Windows 8 driver coming out in the future.

Hope that helped!